# How can I see who offered me the bounty?

Tags: support

Must be a blind spot in my mind, but looking through the list of earned bounties, I could not see who has offered it.

#### Why?

I am about to start a new project on Launchpad, which was initiated by a question on AU, and encouraged by a bounty. I always like to say something like "*thanks for the nice question and the encouragement*" in the about section. Most of the time I remember, but this time I don't, so

*How can I see who offered me the bounty?*

Comment: Why do you assume it was not me? >:-D

Comment: @Rinzwind because it was a +50 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you hover over the blue reputation bonus, you'll see a tooltip come up:

[image]

This also works on the answers directly:

[image]

If you go to a post's timeline, you can also get a direct link to the profile of the person who awarded the bounty:

[image]

To get to a timeline, you can open a post's revision history, and then change the URL to say `/timeline` instead of `/revisions`, or you can [just use a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links/4238#4238).

Comment: Ouch, did I mention the blind spot? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait, are those Windows screenshots? :P

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yes.